# Send email notification for inactive task or bugs----Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How do you configure an Email Notification for an individual user in an organization for not responding in a timeframe?

Eg: An email notification gets sent if Initial Response was not met within say 6 hours of VSO being assigned.

In Azure DevOps project notification settings, it's possible to configure a notification based on the following *actions* taking place on a work item:

[image: Work item notifications]

Notification settings based on a timeout, or lack of response, are not apparent.

Is it possible to configure a notification based on a lack of activity for a work item?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are below pre-defined notifications for work items in Azure Boards.
[image]

See: [Manage your personal notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled#add-a-custom-subscription) for details.

I am afraid that no such notifications are designed for your requirement. However, as a workaround, we can create a query to find those work items which are not changed from `New` for a period when they have been assigned to members, as below.
[image]

Above query will query bugs and tasks which are assigned to members but still state in `New` state and they are created earlier than today across projects. See: [Define a query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) for details.

And clicking "**Email query**" allows you to send this query result to specific members.

[image]